# Android Layout Designer not available in Eclipse 4.2

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-juno

Let me start by saying that I have checked the other questions that this could be considered a "duplicate" of and none of them solved the problem for me.

When I open an Android layout file in Eclipse 4.2, I am unable to open it in the Layout Designer, only in the XML text editor.

There are several similar questions that have been solved, the accepted solutions were to use Open With, or restart eclipse.  I have tried both of these several times but the Android Layout Designer is not in my "Open With" dialog.  There is a Legacy Android Layout Editor but it also does not display the Layout Designer.

I would have posted an image if I had enough reputation.

Comment: You can always upload an image to a photo sharing site and put a link to it.

Comment: Is this the designer you refer to? http://imgur.com/JBubr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly Android ADT plugin not developed properly for Eclipse 4.2 yet, You can switch back to Eclipse Helios with ADT-19 or ADT-20 plugin.

Comment: I installed Indigo(3.7) and the graphical view is available there.  That is a bummer because with 4 there is new themeing so that the entire window can be dark to reduce eye strain.  Oh well I guess I will just have to wait for an updated ADT.  Thanks.

Comment: True with new ADT plugin, Android also advises to use specific version of Eclipse.

Comment: As a follow up, it seems that the theme for completely dark window is interfering.  If I disable the theme and restart, graphical layout is there.

Comment: Did you mean above for Eclipse 4.2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse 4.2 is ok. In Project Explorer go to your project and open activity_main.xml from res >> layout directory.
Once its open on right side look at its bottom. There will be two tabs, click Graphical Layout tab and you will get the Graphical layout back.

Comment: No, the tabs are not there when a non-default theme is applied.  I have used Eclipse (Indigo) for quite a while for Android development. The tabs disappear when the theme is applied in 4.2.